# HTML 5 drag and drop file attachment?

Tags: google, javascript, html5

Looking for a tutorial re implementation of this functionality.

I can only find blog posts saying that gmail added this, but not how it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read this the other day: [How Gmail’s drag and drop works and why it’s not supported in Safari](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-upload)

Comment: Some more examples     
http://jsjoy.com/blog/ext-js-extension-awesome-uploader            


http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/html5-adoption-stories-box-net-and-html5-drag-and-drop/